# jquery : autocomplete returned Name(s) and ID(s)?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, element

Actually I have this html interface;

```
<input type="text" size="20" name="brandname" />
<input type="hidden" name="brandid" value="" />
```

Actually above there is a hidden input value namely as "**brandid**".

And below is the jquery;

```
$('#brandname').autocomplete("searchbrandnames.jsp", {
            minChars: 3
        });
```

OK... the ideas here is that;
Once the user type something into that textfield,
the jquery will work to have a somekind of autocomplete... like what google does for example.

But here, if we notice from the interface above,
There is a hidden value there, Green colored.

That hidden value is going to be used as a hidden variable stored.
That one, that made me question this thread.

What is the best way to obtain **autocomplete into the textfield** and also by **getting the id into the hidden value** as well?
In above example; let's assume,

1. we are typing a brand name into the textfield,
2. then jquery request into the db for some similar brand names,
3. it returned their names with their id; respectively 1 to the textfield and another 1 into the hidden value.

But, as far as I'm working with jquery right now, **many plugins available there**...
**just returned values into a single place nor many values into many places**. I'm saying places means, referring to the html elements.

Hmmm.... is there any turn out for this case?

Comment: You'll want to add `id` attributes to your inputs, matching the `name` attributes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the Autocomplete from jQuery UI

```
$('#brandname').autocomplete({
    source: 'searchbrandnames.jsp',
    minChars: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#brandname').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#brandid').val(ui.item.id)
    },
    search: function() {
        $('#brandid').val('');
    }
});
```

The `value` and `id` item properties will differ depending on the data returned by your JSP file.

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data